# Getting error no such file or directory when running a script

Tags: bash, centos, bash-scripting

Need a bit help. I just wrote my first script to change the network configuration. the code is

```
echo "changing IP to 172.17.51.71"
echo "changing Mask to 255.255.255.0"
echo "changing Gateway to 172.17.51.254"

sed -i 's/.*IPADDR.*$/IPADDR=172.17.51.71/g' /etc/ifcfg-eth0.txt
# ne need to change mask sed -i 's/.*IPADDR.*$/IPADDR=172.17.51.71/g' /etc/ifcfg-eth0
sed -i 's/.*GATEWAY.*$/GATEWAY=172.17.51.254/g' /etc/ifcfg-eth0.txt
```

I copied the `icfg-eth0` file to the `etc` folder for testing purpose. When I run the script I get the error

```
:No such file or diretorytxt
:No such file or diretorytxt
```

But when I just use the commands on the prompt the command works and changes what I want it to change.

Any idea why its not working when running as a script?

AsteriskNOWv3(CentOS 6.2)

Comment: Is that an exact copy/paste of your script? The second `sed` is on a commented-out line, and the middle file doesn't have the .txt extension and doesn't include MASK or 255...?

Comment: Also, how are you running your script?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is you have edited your script on Windows and its lines are terminated with CR-LF instead of the expected single LF.

Use the `dos2unix` command to fix it.

```
dos2unix script
```

Alternatively, you can simply run

```
tr -d `\r` < script > script.fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have added ".txt" to the files you are writing - this would seem wrong, as the bit after the "." is deemed to be a VLAN, and .txt is, of-course not a valid VLAN.